# Custom HTML5 Video Player with "Stats for nerds"

Tags: html, video

I am tasked with looking into a way of building a streaming video testing framework for internal metrics/measurement.

The long and the short of it is that I want to build an HTML5 player that can consume streams and relay performance metrics, specifically

Avg Bitrate
Dropped Frames
Startup Time
Stalls

Reading the html5 spec - I am able to add event listeners for stalls, waits etc, I will be able to build a stats framework from it, but how do I get stuff like dropped frames and bitrate - is that available on any of the modern browsers?

I have been googling, I did find this old discussion on moz, but I haven't been able to find much more.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

My code w/ event listeners....

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<title>Html5 media events</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body >
    <div id="output"></div>
    <video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls autoplay>
        <source src="/ak-5-y.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
    <script>

        var media = document.getElementById('myVideo');

        // Playing event
        var isStalled = function(e) { $("#output").html("Playback Stalled"); };

        var isWaiting = function(e) { $("#output").html("Waiting for content"); };

        var isPlaying = function(e) { $("#output").html("Playing event triggered"); };

        // Pause event
        var onPause = function(e) { $("#output").html("Pause event triggered"); };

        // Volume changed event
        var onVolumechange = function(e) { $("#output").html("Volumechange event triggered"); };

        media.addEventListener("playing", isPlaying, false);    
        media.addEventListener("stalled", isStalled, false); 
        media.addEventListener("waiting", isWaiting, false);   
        media.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
        media.addEventListener("volumechange", onVolumechange, false);

    </script>   
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using browser's native html5 player to play m3u8/dash?

Answer (score 0):

You can get dropped frames using VideoPlayBackQuality interface.

Refer:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement/getVideoPlaybackQuality
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VideoPlaybackQuality